# C++: How can 2 classes call each other without redeclaration and without headers calling each other

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

I have a bit of problem with this. I have a class A which instantiates an object of B and then B which instantiates an object of A. Is this at all possible? I tried adding this in the headers of each

```
#ifndef A
#define A
  class a...
#endif
```

but if keeps me in an infinite header loop which it reaches the maximum header includes, so obviously one is calling the other and the other is calling that one. Is there any way to achieve this?

edit: Okay this seems like a good answer but now A complains that B doesn't have a Constructor despite the fact that it definitely has a constructor. I can't figure that one out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can forward declare the classes, for example:

`A.h`:

```
class B;

class A
{
    B* a_;
};
```

`B.h`:

```
class A;

class B
{
    A* a_;
};
```

In your source files where you actually use the classes (that is, create them, destroy them, use their members, etc.), you will need to include both headers so that their definitions are available:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

Comment: Using a smart pointer is recommended to simplify your destructor a little. :-) If one class is using `shared_ptr`, the other should be a `weak_ptr`, to avoid circular references.

Comment: Would this mean I don't have to use the #include A or B anymore in those classes or headers?

Comment: @John Baker : Yes, you don't need to include A.h or B.h. Actually, you really shouldn't !

Comment: Yeah for some reason this won't work for me. Now it just says undeclared identifier A

Comment: With the given example, if you have separate headers for the two classes (which is a good idea), you would need to include `B.h` in `A.h` (but not `A.h` in `B.h`).  You can avoid doing this by forward declaring `B` in `A.h` as well.  You will have to include both `A.h` and `B.h` in source files (`.cpp`s) that make use of classes `A` and `B`.

Comment: Oh man that is confusing. Could I beg for an ammended sample?

Comment: Yes your sample is absolutely perfect! Now I get it. Thanks A TON! Definitely got the accepted answer, solved my problem perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You should break this circular dependence. For instance, you could use a pointer to B, and you could then forward declare the B class.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using forward declaration?

```
class B;

class A
{
  private:
     B* instanceOfB_;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good design to start with. However to make it possible just use forward declaration.

In classA.h file remove any includes to classB.h and move them to the classA.cpp. Then before declaring classA write the line `class B;` to forward declare class B. This way you can have member variables of B* (but not B) inside class A. Do the same for classB next.

Answer (score 2):

You can forward declare A in B's header file, and the other way around, to achieve what you want.

```
// In B.h
class A;

class B
{
  private:
    A a;
};
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) for more information.

Comment: That all depends on whether you want a pointer to an a or a value member. Value members are just as valid as pointer members.

Comment: Håvard: you can't forward-declare a value member of a class, because its size is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `class A {B b;};` and `class B {A a;}`, no you can't.  Class data members are included in the class, so you'd have a B that included an A that included a B that included an A....  Remember, in C++ a data object is not a reference to something, but is the actual thing.

You need something like `class A {B * b;};` and `class B {A * a;}`, where you are providing pointers.  Before the definitions, you need something like `class A; class B;` to tell the compiler that `A` and `B` are classes.  These are called "forward declarations".